# What is the default data structure the tables in the database in MySQL are stored in?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I googled around a bit and learned about the concept of indexing, clustered and non clustered indexes and that the tables defined with a primary/foreign key automatically creates an index on that field. But i was wondering what would be the default data structure or method for storing the tables for which we haven't declared any primary/foreign key? Would this too be indexed?(If yes!! then on what field?) Or is it upto the DBMS to set this data structure by default?. I am very keen about knowing all this stuff...

Comment: It will not be indexed. An index comes from adding an index. A primary key implies an index.

Comment: Have a look at the manual chapters [The InnoDB Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) and [Alternative Storage Engines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html). It's definitely too broad to explain it here in an answer.